# Returning List value using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

Actually I want to return the data from different lists based on Date. When i'm using this i'm getting data upto @Var result but i'm unnable to return the data.  The issue with this is i'm getting error @return result. I want to return the data @return result. I'm using Linq C#. Can anyone help me out?

```
    public List<CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails> GetAllCustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportCustomer()
    {
        var cbsalesreeport = (from cb in db.cashbilldescriptions
                              join c in db.cashbills on cb.CashbillId equals c.CashbillId
                              join p in db.products on cb.ProductId equals p.ProductId


                              select new
                              {
                                  Productamount = cb.Productamount,
                                  ProductName = p.ProductDescription,
                                  CashbillDate = c.Date
                              }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ASZ.AmoghGases.Model.CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails
                            {

                                Productdescription = x.ProductName,
                                Alldates = x.CashbillDate,
                                TotalAmount = x.Productamount
                            }).ToList();

        var invsalesreeport = (from inv in db.invoices
                               join invd in db.invoicedeliverychallans on inv.InvoiceId equals invd.InvoiceId
                               select new
                               {
                                   Productamount = invd.Total,
                                   ProductName = invd.Productdescription,
                                   InvoiceDate = inv.Date
                               }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ASZ.AmoghGases.Model.CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails
                            {

                                Productdescription = x.ProductName,
                                Alldates = x.InvoiceDate,
                                TotalAmount = x.Productamount
                            }).ToList();
        var abc = cbsalesreeport.Union(invsalesreeport).ToList();

        var result = (from i in abc
                 group i by new { Date = i.Alldates.ToString("MMM"), Product = i.Productdescription } into grp
                 select new { Month = grp.Key, Total = grp.Sum(i => i.TotalAmount) });

        **return result;**

    }
```

Comment: it should be `return result.ToList()` really. Because `Select` returns you an `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Callum. `result` is not an `IEnumerable<CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails>` so the OP will just get another error if they try that

Comment: You need to tell us what properties `CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails` has, otherwise we cannot answer this question.

Comment: You are trying to return anonymous class instances from the method. Your `abc` variable is of correct type (list of `CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails`), but your `result` variable is grouping these values into a list of anonymous classes `{ Month, Total }`. Take a moment to stop and rethink what you really want to get from this method. Most likely, your method return type must be a list of a new class containing these properties (not `CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails`).

Comment: @Jamiec yeah I specifically didnt comment on what resulting types would be, just that you can't return an `IEnumerable` when the type being asked for is a `List`

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert your `result` to a `List` before returning it using `return result.ToList()` or make your method return an `IEnumerable<CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails>` instead of `List`.

As your result is an enumeration of anonymous types you have to convert them to your `CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails`-type first:

```
select new CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails{ Month = grp.Key, Total = grp.Sum(i => i.TotalAmount) });
```

Assuming your type has exactly the members returned by the select.

EDIT: So your code should look like this:

```
var result = (from i in abc
             group i by new { Date = i.Alldates.ToString("MMM"), Product = i.Productdescription } into grp
             select new CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails{ Month = grp.Key, Total = grp.Sum(i => i.TotalAmount) });

return result.ToList();
```

Comment: `result` is an enumerable of anonymous objects. Neither suggestion will work.

Comment: And your update has made this even worse - you cant "cast" a list of anonymous objects to a list of strongly typed object. Noway. nohow.

Comment: Ok, a little better, you still use the word "cast" (which is incorrect) but your example is at least *projecting* to a correct typed instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume Alldates property if is date of one of groups that month of date is in right place:

```
var result = (from i in abc
   group i by new { Date = i.Alldates.ToString("MMM"), Product = i.Productdescription } 
   into grp
   select new CustomerWiseMonthlySalesReportDetails{ 
          Productdescription = grp.Key.Product, 
          TotalAmount = grp.Sum(i => i.TotalAmount), 
          Alldates =grp.First(i=>i.Alldates ) })
   .ToList();
```